# "Optional" package accept variable argument

Tags: variable

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[test]{optional}

\begin{document}
\def\optname{test}
\optname  \\  % Prints "test"
\opt{\optname}{
    TEST    % does nothing
}\\
\opt{test}{
    TEST 2    % behaves as expected
}
\end{document}
```

The above minimal example uses the "optional" package to compile different Versions of the same document. Now I'd like to expand it that the `\opt` command uses a predefined variable to determine in which version which part of the document gets compiled. The Problem is, that it does not accept the variable. I feel it's some kind of expansion issue, but i haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `\opt` can be expanded by `\expandafter`. Then the macro will see `test` directly instead of the option hidden in the macro `\optname`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[test]{optional}

\begin{document}
\def\optname{test}
\optname  \\  % Prints "test"
\expandafter\opt\expandafter{\optname}{
    TEST
}\\
\opt{test}{
    TEST 2    % behaves as expected
}
\end{document}
```